# In R: How to aggregate entire rows based on the max value in a certain column by day?

Tags: r

below is an example of my data set:

```
date                O3  NOX SO2
01/01/1994 06:00    7   14  29
01/01/1994 07:00    5   18  30
01/01/1994 08:00    3   18  29
01/01/1994 09:00    6   24  35
01/01/1994 10:00    20  42  52
01/02/1994 06:00    19  7   11
01/02/1994 07:00    19  6   16
01/02/1994 08:00    42  10  4
01/02/1994 09:00    25  17  26
01/02/1994 10:00    36  29  13
01/03/1994 06:00    10  1   6
01/03/1994 07:00    14  2   5
01/03/1994 08:00    24  4   4
01/03/1994 09:00    57  11  6
01/03/1994 10:00    39  34  11
```

Using R, what I want to do is aggregating or subsetting entire rows based on the max value in a given column by day, in this case selecting the entire row that contains the max O3 value in each day.

My code only aggregates the O3 column and date but deletes the hour in which is was recorded.

with aggregate:

`agg.df <- aggregate(df["O3"]~., format(df["date"],"%Y-%j"),max, na.rm = TRUE)`

or with dplyr package:

`agg.df<-df %>%
  collapse_by("daily") %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  summarise(O3 = max(var))`

I want to obtain something like this:

```
date             O3 NOX SO2
01/01/1994 10:00 20 42  52
02/01/1994 08:00 42 10  4 
03/01/1994 09:00 57 11  6
...
```

Where the final subset includes entire rows with the max value in O3 per day.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: This will keep all rows where the `O3` is equal to the max of that day. If you want only 1 per row, you could use `slice` or `top_n` to accomplish that.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat %>%
  group_by(day = lubridate::date(date)) %>%
  filter(O3 == max(O3)) %>% 
  ungroup %>%
  select(date, O3, NOX, SO2, -day)

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  date                   O3   NOX   SO2
  <dttm>              <int> <int> <int>
1 1994-01-01 10:00:00    20    42    52
2 1994-02-01 08:00:00    42    10     4
3 1994-03-01 09:00:00    57    11     6
```

#### data

```
dat <- structure(list(O3 = c(7L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 20L, 19L, 19L, 42L, 25L, 
                             36L, 10L, 14L, 24L, 57L, 39L), NOX = c(14L, 18L, 18L, 24L, 42L, 
                                                                    7L, 6L, 10L, 17L, 29L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 11L, 34L), SO2 = c(29L, 30L, 
                                                                                                                          29L, 35L, 52L, 11L, 16L, 4L, 26L, 13L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 11L), 
                      date = structure(c(757404000, 757407600, 757411200, 757414800, 
                                         757418400, 760082400, 760086000, 760089600, 760093200, 760096800, 
                                         762501600, 762505200, 762508800, 762512400, 762516000), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
                                                                                                                          "POSIXt"))), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L
                                                                                                                          ), .Names = c("O3", "NOX", "SO2", "date"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider calculating max O3 with `ave`, then subetting accordingly:

```
dat$Max_O3 <- with(dat, ave(O3, as.Date(date), FUN=max))

subset(dat, O3 == Max_O3)
#    O3 NOX SO2                date Max_O3
# 5  20  42  52 1994-01-01 10:00:00     20
# 8  42  10   4 1994-02-01 08:00:00     42
# 14 57  11   6 1994-03-01 09:00:00     57
```